# Find angle $x$ in the circumference below

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, plane-geometry

"From the endpoints of diameter OO′of the outer circle we construct, on the same side, two tangents to the inner circle. Prove they are perpendicular.
[image]

I think

Since the base of the triangle is the diameter the angle would be worth $90^o$ . But since it would be a very simple solution, he put the angle outside the circumference. I believe that the idea here would be to show that the tangents are perpendicular to each other and therefore $x$ would be worth $90^o$ and belong to the circumference. But I couldn't do this demosntration

To help with the simplified resolution that was posted.

$\triangle YO'P: YP^2 = (R+x)^2 - r^2$

T.Fuss: $\dfrac{R+x}{R-x} = \dfrac{\sqrt{(R+x)^2-r^2}}r = \dfrac{YP}{r} = cotg(\angle XYZ) = \frac1{\dfrac{R-x}{R+x}} = tg (\angle XZY)$

$\triangle ZQO': ZQ^2 + r^2 = (R-x)^2 \implies ZQ = \sqrt{(R-x)^2 - r^2}$

T.Fuss: $\dfrac{R-x}{R+x} = \dfrac{\sqrt{(R-x)^2- r^2}}r = \dfrac{ZQ}r = cotg(\angle XZY)$

$\therefore \angle XZY + \angle XYZ = 90^{\circ} \implies \angle ZXY = 90^{\circ}$
[image]

(Credits: FelipeMartin)

Comment: The assumptions aren't clear (to me, at least).  Is $O$ the center of the circle?  What is $O'$?  What are the other figures?  As you say, if the point in question is actually on the circumference, then the answer is $\frac {\pi}2$ (and all of the extra information is irrelevant), but if it isn't on the circumference, I don't see that you have enough information to determine it.

Comment: @lulu   O' is clear ...center of the circle inscribed in the quadrilateral

Comment: t's a Peruvian question...the solutions are not always so simple to visualize...

Comment: But we have no information on the quadrilateral.

Comment: @lulu Just look at the representation of the arrows that are the rays

Comment: What does that tell us?

Comment: Remember, not all quadrilaterals are cyclic.  That looks like an inscribed circle, but is that specified?  What do you get if the quadrilateral is a square centered at $O$?

Comment: @lulu  You asked:  Is O the center of the circle? What is O′. I answer...

Comment: My point is that we are asked to guess a lot of things here. Anyway, I'd start with the inscribed square.  That special case should be easy enough.

Comment: But the quadrilateron is inscribed ... there is no doubt about it. The question is for someone who can see a solution. Everything is clear to me

Comment: In the case of the inscribed square, the point in question is indeed on the circumference.   So, if the result is meant to be the same for *all* inscribed cyclic quadrilaterals then that must be the answer. Of course, that still needs to be demonstrated.

Comment: The base of the triangle is also a diameter of the outer circle. Hence $x=90°$.

Comment: @Intelligentipauca This is clear, but since x is not on the circle it is necessary to show that the tangent are perpendicular

Comment: @Intelligentipauca It would be pointless to propose an exercise, even more of the Peruvian line, with a direct answer.

Comment: $x$ is not on the outer circle? How is $x$ defined then?

Comment: @Intelligentipauca See that in the drawing $x$ is inside the circle. The vertex does not touch the circle

Comment: Maybe like this: "From the endpoints of diameter $OO'$ of the outer circle we construct, on the same side, two tangents to the inner circle. Prove they are perpendicular."?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/145949/discussion-between-peta-arantes-and-intelligenti-pauca).

Answer (score 4):

Let $r,R,X$ be the inradius, circumradius and $OO'$.

By Fuss' Theorem for bicentric quadrilaterals $$\frac{1}{(R-X)^2}+\frac{1}{(R+X)^2}=\frac{1}{r^2}.$$
This can be rewritten as $$\frac{R+X}{R-X}=\frac{\sqrt{(R+X)^2-r^2}}{r}.$$

In the triangle containing angle $x$ draw in the lines of length $r$ from $O'$ to the opposite sides of the triangle. This produces two right-angled triangles and the above equation shows that these are similar.

This immediately gives $x=90^0$.

Comment: Thank you for your help, but I didn't understand what you said, could you make or use the picture of the statement to explain it better?

Comment: Are you happy with the first three lines of the proof?

Comment: I don't understand that the height of the triangle containing x equals r

Comment: r is the length of a radius of the incircle.

Comment: I have improved the description

Comment: But it is not the height of the triangle that contains x